# How to get selected image's[multiple/all] value which is placed inside <LI>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on ID card image[multiple] which is inside an LI element and in this process I have come up with below code. For single image path it is working fine. The requirement is to populate all the selected images path, when user click on "printBtn" button. I need to achieve it for PDF conversion(printing purpose). Any help? Thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```
<div class="idcard-cont">
    <ul>
       <li>
        <img src="../../images/img-IDcard.gif" alt="" />
       </li>
       <li>
         <img src="../../images/img-IDcard.gif" alt="" />
       </li>
      <li>
        <img src="../../images/img-IDcard.gif" alt="" />
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
    <input type="button" value="Print" id="printBtn" />
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(".idcard-cont").find("li").on('click', function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass("selected");
        if($this.hasClass("selected")){
            alert($this.html());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#printBtn').click(function(){
    var urls=[];
    $('.idcard-cont .selected').each(function(){
        urls.push($(this).find('img').attr('src'));
    });
    console.log(urls); //contains all the selected imgs
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to add to an array

I'm not an expert at jQuery by no means but maybe something like

```
var list = new Array();

$(".idcard-cont").find("li").on('click', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass("selected");
    if($this.hasClass("selected")){
        list.push(item.text);
    }
});

console.log(list.length);
```